# Images are not displaying from custom email template on localhost in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-images, email-templates

I am getting image in my custom email template but image is not showing in email sent from my localhost. I just need to know why the images are not loading/visible in my email?

Comment: Where should i put the code to run my image files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is loaded from the server when the email is opened. My guess is you are sending the email to a Gmail account. When you do that, Google proxies the image to protect your identity by not having your IP hit the Magento server.

Either move the image to a publicly accessible location or setup a staging server to test the whole site on a public server. Since Google can't hit your local server, that image will never load.

Comment: yes i am using gmail account @krishna. What should i do to display image ?

Comment: Url of image is something like this    https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/iuQ0uXtveltZSIc4jP3mDG0Ixw4YqXqh5OS4vaFQncbzCx-bEYHJSnxP6wst8v-shHLSm-vVCP3ztk_6hBu8ygtRTmEky5ADjBC3eDnglumZ69c=s0-d-e1-ft#http://pub/media/catalog/product/8/1/81zwjhgqkml._sl1500_.jpg

Comment: I guess image has not been loaded on server ?

Comment: Yes, Either move the image to a publicly accessible location or setup a staging server to test the whole site on a public server. Since Google can't hit your local server, that image will never load.

Comment: Ok i got it @Krishna. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but it can help.
To test my email images, i use a JS script that remove Google Proxy Address from the `img src` :

Open the email in gmail, open a console with inspector, copy/paste this code and run it :

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    console.log(images[i].src);
    images[i].src=images[i].src.replace(/^https:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.\/\-=_]+#/,'');
}
```

Comment: what is the proper solution ?

Comment: Now days i am getting such url that actually after replacing whole url also with above script i am not getting theme path in the url anywhere.